# Mixed fulltext and exact matching on neo4j index

Tags: java, lucene, full-text-search, neo4j

In my Neo4j database, I have a standard lucene index setup against nodes called "posts" which I end up doing a combined AND query to filter out nodes.  One of which is an exact match (feedid) one is a range of long values (date range) and one a fulltext lookup.

I've set the index to the default 'exact' type and the text (contains) searching is only achievable by using wildcard *term* style searching which is a bit slow.

I think I can get the text lookup to run faster by using full-text searching but I can't seem to combine the two (exact and fulltext) together to form one query.

Is there a way of adding fulltext search to one of my fields in my index or basically get a query to do a lookup on exact and fulltext on a set of indexed nodes?

Many thanks! James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An index can either be 'exact' or 'fulltext' for all the fields, you can't have different type of fields in the same index. For your problem, you can use multiple indexes. Or you could decide to do some of the filtering on the properties value instead of index lookups. That depends a lot on your data model and on the size of your graph.

Comment: Thank you for you answer that's helpful.  Do you know if there is a difference in performance between lookup on a fulltext field compared to lookup on an exact field when the value is simply a string with no whitespaces?

Comment: I think is the same. The only difference should be in indexing time between the two, and not in the lookup time. You could perhaps get more information from Lucene documentation.